# How do I mock window.close and window.closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I currently want to mock two window properties which is `close` and `closed. When window.close() is called, I expect that window.closed would equal true

```
export function createWindowMock(partnerWindow: Window): Window {
 const closeSpy =  () => {
    jest.spyOn(partnerWindow, 'closed').mockImplementation(false);
  }

  jest.spyOn(partnerWindow, 'close').mockImplementation(closeSpy);

  return {
    ...partnerWindow,
  };
}
```

My current problem is under my closeSpy declaration, i'm getting a typeError `Argument of type '"closed"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"opener"'.` and is also not working out for me. I tried alternatives like:

```
export function createWindowMock(partnerWindow: Window): Window {
 let closed = false;
 const closeSpy =  () => {
    closed = true;
  }

  jest.spyOn(partnerWindow, 'close').mockImplementation(closeSpy);

  return {
    ...partnerWindow,
    closed,
  };
}
```

but still, closed is still returning as false. What can I possibly do to to make this work?

Comment: Shouldn't you [use](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype) `jest.spyOn(partnerWindow, 'closed', 'get')` since it's a property, not a method?

Comment: Ah. You are right but how do I change it true? @Thomas

Comment: `jest.spyOn(partnerWindow, 'closed', 'get').mockReturnValue(true)`

Comment: strangely it is telling me that `closed property does not exist` @adsy